# Spring project choice doesn't appear after installing STS plugin in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, spring, spring-tool-suite, new-project

I have installed the STS (Spring Tools Suite) plugin in Eclipse Luna in order to create a Spring project.
But the Spring project choice doesn't appear. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Try restarting it. Or shift to STS maybe...

Comment: i acually restarted it so many times..but nothing changed..there is no spring project in the choices given..

Comment: It is supported on  
Mars (4.5), Luna (4.4), Kepler (4.3), Juno (4.2, 3.8), Previous to Juno (<=4.1) Versions on eclipse...

Comment: yeah, and i tried it also on eclipse Mars, but the same thing, it doen't show

Comment: Hmmm. Shall not be a problem. It worked fine for me. But afterwards, I shifted to STS. Its much better... :D

Comment: what do you mean by shift to sts plz ? the pb is that i can't find spring project, so that i can choose the spring mvc architecture...can you please clarify your answer..thank you

Comment: By shifting to STS, I mean that I left working on Mars (uninstalled it) and Installed the Spring Tool Suite instead...

Comment: i actually installed the sts tools, but how can i use a spring project on it? wht are the steos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this link and first download fresh STS and follow the steps:
Step 1: [Downlaod STS-32 bits windows OS](http://dist.springsource.com/release/STS/3.7.2.RELEASE/dist/e4.5/spring-tool-suite-3.7.2.RELEASE-e4.5.1-win32.zip)
Step 2: [How to create New SPRING MVC project in STS](https://dzone.com/articles/springide-using-spring-eclipse)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't show cause after installing it you restarted eclipse without letting it finish installing software (When you install the plugin look at the bar at the bottom of eclipse IDE )